# Migrating to from glMatrix 1 to glMatrix 2

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra, gl-matrix

I haven't been able to update these functions from an old application using glMatrix 1.2 to glMatrix 2.7:

```
calculateNormal() {
    mat4.identity(this.normalMatrix);
    mat4.set(this.modelViewMatrix, this.normalMatrix);
    mat4.inverse(this.normalMatrix);
    mat4.transpose(this.normalMatrix);
}
```

And the following function of multiplying a matrix by a 4-component vector doesn't exist:

```
calculateOrientation() {
    mat4.multiplyVec4(this.matrix, [1, 0, 0, 0], this.right);
    mat4.multiplyVec4(this.matrix, [0, 1, 0, 0], this.up);
    mat4.multiplyVec4(this.matrix, [0, 0, 1, 0], this.normal);
}
```

Comment: In common the normal matrix is 3*3 matrix (`mat3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In common the normal matrix is 3*3 matrix ([`mat3`](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat3.html)).

But anyway, [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/) is well documented and according to the documentation of [`mat4`](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat4.html) and [`vec4`](http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-vec4.html), your code can be ported like this:

```
calculateNormal() {
    this.normalMatrix = mat4.clone(this.modelViewMatrix);
    mat4.invert(this.normalMatrix, this.normalMatrix);
    mat4.transpose(this.normalMatrix, this.normalMatrix);
}
```

May be it is not necessary to `create` the vectors in the following, but I don't kow if the vectors are existing in your case:

```
calculateOrientation() {

    this.right = vec4.create();
    vec4.set( this.right, 1, 0, 0, 0 );
    vec4.transformMat4( this.right, this.right, this.matrix );

    this.up = vec4.create();
    vec4.set( this.up, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
    vec4.transformMat4( this.up, this.up, this.matrix );

    this.normal = vec4.create();
    vec4.set( this.normal, 0, 0, 1, 0 );
    vec4.transformMat4( this.normal, this.normal, this.matrix );
}
```